# In IIS, why app in application pool always stops and IIS service becomes Unavailable (503)

Tags: asp.net, windows, iis

I have changed my domain user's password, run iisreset many times and I met this problem

It was fine to open my local site at the first time, but if I refresh it or click any link on that page (which is also in my local server) I always got a 503 error Service Unavailable.

And the app relates to the unavailable site also automatically stopped, even after I manually restart it. If I tried to restart the app, it said it could not start if WAS (windows activation service) service is not running. But restarting the WAS service didn't help anything.

Even if I run iisreset, the local website is still available only at the first (or second) visit.

Any one knows how to solve this problem ?

PS: My system is windows 2012 R2, IIS version is 6.2

Thanks

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Comment: Check if you use this domain user as application pool identity. If so, you need to update its password stored in IIS configuration.

Comment: No, I don't need authentication.

Answer (score 2):

A request comes into your server, it is picked up by http.sys (the kernel part of IIS) it doesn't know what to do with it and asks WAS (Windows activation service), WAS checks the configuration and figures out the web site and application pool to be used for this request. If the pool is not running, it is trying to start it.
If it can't start the pool, it reports back to http.sys: "sorry, I tried but I can't start the pool" At this point http.sys has no option but responding that the service for this request is not available.

If you look at the response header of your failed request, you will most likely see a

```
Server: Microsoft HTTPAPI/2.0
```

rather than a

```
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
```

that means the response comes from http.sys rather than the user mode part of IIS.

The HTTPERR log `%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR` may have some helpful information.

Maybe the request made it into the log file for the site, the http sub-status code next to the `503` may be helpful to know.

Most often, the pool can not be started due to authentication problems. Double check the identity of the pool. Use the security event log or [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem. One application running once and then letting the AppPool stopped and the IIS returning 50x errors.

There is an exception going on somewhere. If you look at the Event Viewer I am quite sure you will get more info about the problem you are facing. If you do find more info and still need more help please post it here.

EDIT:

Please note that you can go to your IIS, in the websites select your website, then double click on "Error Pages" on the right (Features View), then on the right click on Edit Feature Settings, Select Details Errors.

In your browser: IE: Tools -> Internet Options -> Advanced -> Show Friendly HTTP Error Messages should be unselected. This might also help on debugging your problem.

Comment: No such exception in Windows Logs\Application

Comment: Please look at the EDIT and see if that helps.